# Fitting dynamic text into a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I couldn't find any answers on Google and Stack Overflow on how to fit text into a table so that the words go to the next line. The only solutions I found that were almost helpful were "making table cells fixed, but the text still runs off the page".

When the text is short:
http://puu.sh/d4IQ2/7a7c95512c.jpg

When the text is too long:
http://puu.sh/d4ITM/6edb003a7c.jpg

How do I make it so that the spaces in the table are fixed based on the window size, then have the text that is too long increase the height of the table row and go onto the next line.

For example, my table is like this:

```
+------+-----+-----+--------+
| 12345|12345|12345|  12345 |
|------+-----+-----+--------|
| 12345| 123 |  1  |   123  |
|------+-----+-----+--------|
|123456|12345| 123 |12345678|
|------+-----+-----+--------|
| 12345| 123 |12345|  1234  |
+-----+-----+-----+---------+
```

when I want it like this:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|12345|12345|12345|12345|
|-----+-----+-----+-----|
|12345| 123 |  1  | 123 |
|-----+-----+-----+-----|
|12345|12345| 123 |12345|
|  6  |     |     | 678 |
|-----+-----+-----+-----|
|12345| 123 |12345| 1234|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

style.css:

`table, th{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    table-layout:fixed
    padding: 15px;
}`

The PHP code is too long, and I don't want to list out all the functions, the rows and text in the cells are looped where I get data from SQL database:

```
<table style = "width = 100%">
  <tr> 
    <th> looped text </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: a "max-width" should do the trick,check out my answer below..

Answer (score 0):

Set the `td` size equally for each `td` tag

```
<td width="25%">Name</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the columns a specified width in the CSS. This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

add this in css file

```
  td {
      width : 300px !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `table-layout:fixed` to the table element (not the th), and add `word-wrap:break-word` to the th/td's.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rz1fmvk/

Answer (score -1):

Well,i think a solution is to set a max-width style for your table.In this way the table width won't exceed the given max-width,and the only thing that remains for the value is to go beneath.

```
<table style="max-width: 500px; width: 500px;">
</table>
```

Also,specify a width.
Of course the style should be in an extern css file,but you get the idea.Hope it helps.

```
table{
 width: 500px;
 max-width:500px
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to fixed witdh of th and for td put css word-wrap: break-word; sample below. You can change the width of th.

```
  table{
     width:100%:
    }
    th{
       width:30%;
    }
    td{
     word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```